# Request future keeps sending null paramaters

Tags: java, php, android, json, asynchronous

I am trying to pass parameters to a php file via RequestFuture in an
 asynctask. The class i am executing it from is my main activity, but
 the problem is that when i execute the asynctask it has not been
 sending the paramater over. and most recently i have been getting a
 wierd error   this is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView textv;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public Context c;
    public parseActivity a;
    private JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    public JSONObject js;
    public static String stat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        a = new parseActivity();
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in...");
        final Button logb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        logb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                if(view == logb) {

                        String user = username.getText().toString();
                        String pass = password.getText().toString();

                    try {
                        params.put("username", user);
                        params.put("password", pass);
                        Log.w("tag", "doInBackground: "+params.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    textv.setText(params.toString());
                       c = getApplicationContext();
                       caller caller = new caller(params,c);
                       caller.execute();
                }

            }
        });

    }

}
```

> as you can see i'm executing the async class which is here

```
public class caller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject> {
    private parseActivity p = new parseActivity();
    private JSONObject params;
    private Context c;
    private JSONObject js;
    public caller(JSONObject  param, Context context){
       params = param;
       c = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void...param) {

        RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
       JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,p.URLS,params ,future,future);

        MySingleton.getInstance(c).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        try {
              js = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Log.w("tag", "doInBackground: "+js);

            return js ;
        }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
            e.getCause();
           return null;
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

here is my php code which has no errors.

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST))
     {  
       if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
       {
        echo json_encode(array("username" => $_POST['username'], "password" => $_POST['password']));
       }else{json_encode(array("error" => "nothing set"));}
     }else{json_encode(array("error" => "nothing set"));}
    ?>
```

> and here is the error i am getting

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.doGet(RequestFuture.java:117)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.get(RequestFuture.java:97)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at com.thetenlaws.password.caller.doInBackground(caller.java:45)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at com.thetenlaws.password.caller.doInBackground(caller.java:26)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-21 16:22:19.378 14198-14453/com.thetenlaws.password W/System.err: Caused by: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Answer (score 0):

luckily I found the solution because im pretty sure i am not the only one who has to deal with something like this the problem is not on the client side it is with the server side i was sending an object with post so it did not recognize the object as a post variable so in order to fix it you need to capture that sent object and put it in a php variable just add

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

to the top of the php script and use the $data varable as your post array expample $data['username'] and another thing if anyone who had experienced this problem before and viewed this post and said nothing just know i am very disqusted good by